# Date is not displaying on x axis in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am saving the patient details in the sqlite database. Patient details includes BP,sugar, creatinin, date, time of admission. Regarding BP I am storing Systolic and Diastolic values in the database. I want to show the values and date entered by the user in the graph. I am trying to show the date in x axis which is stored in the database. But I am not getting the date on x-axis.

ViewBloodPressureActivity.java

```
public class ViewBloodPressureActivity extends Activity {

    SQLiteDatabase db;
    String pName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_blood_pressure);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        String gName = intent.getExtras().getString("GroupName");
        pName = intent.getExtras().getString("PatientName");

        Cursor cursor = null;

        TextView tvPatientName = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textViewPatientNameViewBP);
        TextView tvDate = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textViewPatientBPDate);
        TextView tvTime = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textViewPatientBPTime);
        TextView tvSystolic = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textViewPatientBPSystolic);
        TextView tvDiastolic = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textViewPatientBPDiastolic);
        TextView tvNumOfRecords = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textViewPatientBPNumOfRecords);

        Button back = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.buttonPatientBPBack);
        Button trend = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.buttonPatientBPTrend);

        tvPatientName.setText(pName);

        openPatientBPDatabase();
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM PatntBP WHERE PatientName = '"+pName+"';", null);
        int rows = cursor.getCount();
        tvNumOfRecords.setText(" "+rows+" for this patient");
        switch (rows) {
            case 0:Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No records in Database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();break;
            case 1: {   cursor.moveToFirst(); 
                        tvDate.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date")));
                        tvTime.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("time")));
                        tvSystolic.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("systolic")));
                        tvDiastolic.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("diastolic")));
                        break;
            }
            default : {
                Log.v("BPDB", "There are :"+cursor.getCount()+" records.");
                cursor.moveToLast();
                tvDate.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date")));
                tvTime.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("time")));
                tvSystolic.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("systolic")));
                tvDiastolic.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("diastolic")));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Use Charts to view the Data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        closePatientBPDatabase();

        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(ViewBloodPressureActivity.this, ListPatientForViewHDActivity.class);
                intent.setAction(action);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        trend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(ViewBloodPressureActivity.this, TrendAnalysisForBPActivity.class);
                intent.setAction(action);
                intent.putExtra("PatientName", pName);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    private void closePatientBPDatabase() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.close();
    }

    private void openPatientBPDatabase() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("HCDatabase", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PatntBP (GroupName VARCHAR, PatientName VARCHAR, systolic VARCHAR, diastolic VARCHAR, date VARCHAR, time VARCHAR);");
    }

    public void lineGraphHandler(View view) {
        LineGraph lineGraph = new LineGraph();
        Intent lineIntent = lineGraph.getIntent(this);
        startActivity(lineIntent);
    }

    private class LineGraph {

        public Intent getIntent(Context context) {


            //SQLiteDatabase db = context.openOrCreateDatabase("HCDatabase", 0, null);
            // Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM PatntBP", new String[] { pName });
            SQLiteDatabase db1 = openOrCreateDatabase("HCDatabase", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM PatntBP where PatientName = '"+pName+"';";
            Log.v("BP Query", sqlQuery);
            Cursor cursor = db1.rawQuery(sqlQuery, null);


            int rows = cursor.getCount();
            int y[] = new int[rows];
            int y1[] = new int[rows];

            if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int i = 0;
                do {
                    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PatientName"));
                    String systolic = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("systolic"));
                    String diastolic = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("diastolic"));
                    String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"));
                    String[] ss = date.split("/");
                    Log.v("BP Query", "Row : "+name+" "+systolic+" "+diastolic+" "+ss[1]);
                    y[i] = Integer.parseInt(systolic);
                    y1[i] = Integer.parseInt(diastolic);
                    i++;
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            db1.close();
            int x[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

            int x1[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

            TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Systolic");
            for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
                series.add(x[i], y[i]);
            }

            TimeSeries series1 = new TimeSeries("Diastolic");
            for (int i = 0; i < y1.length; i++) {
                series1.add(x1[i], y1[i]);
            }

            XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
            dataset.addSeries(series);
            dataset.addSeries(series1); 

            XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

            XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
            renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
            renderer.setColor(Color.RED);

            XYSeriesRenderer renderer1 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
            renderer1.setPointStyle(PointStyle.DIAMOND);
            renderer1.setColor(Color.BLUE);

            mRenderer.setChartTitle("Blood Pressure Variation");
            mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
            mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer1);
            mRenderer.setYAxisMax(200);
            mRenderer.setYAxisMin(40);

            Intent intent = ChartFactory.getTimeChartIntent(context, dataset, mRenderer, "Blood Pressure Graph");
            return intent;
        }

    }

}
```

EnterBloodPressureActivity.java

```
public class EnterBloodPressureActivity extends Activity {

    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Date date;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter_blood_pressure);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
        Date date = new Date();
        String dateStringAndTime = sdf.format(date);
        String dateAndTime[] = dateStringAndTime.split(" ");
        String dateString = dateAndTime[0];
        String timeString = dateAndTime[1];

        final EditText etSystolic = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editTextSystolic);
        final EditText etDiastolic = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editTextDiastolic);
        final EditText etDate = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editTextBPDate);
        etDate.setText(dateString);
        final EditText etTime = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editTextBPTime);
        etTime.setText(timeString);

        TextView patientName = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textViewEnterBPDataPatientName);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        patientName.setText(intent.getExtras().getString("PatientName"));

        Button save = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.buttonBPDataSave);
        Button reset = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.buttonBPDataReset);
        Button back = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.buttonBPDataBack);

        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                openPatientBPDatabase();
                //get  GroupName and PatientName
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                String gName = intent.getExtras().getString("GroupName");
                String pName = intent.getExtras().getString("PatientName");

                // ensure input data is not null
                String systolic = etSystolic.getText().toString();
                String diastolic = etDiastolic.getText().toString();
                String date = etDate.getText().toString();
                String time = etTime.getText().toString();
                if (!systolic.equals("") && !diastolic.equals("") && !date.equals("") && !time.equals("")) {
                    String sqlStmt = "INSERT INTO PatntBP VALUES('"+gName+"', '"+pName+"', '"+systolic+"', '"+diastolic+"', '"+date+"', '"+time+"');";
                    Log.v("BP DEBUG", sqlStmt); 
                    db.execSQL(sqlStmt);
                    closePatientBPDatabase();
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(EnterBloodPressureActivity.this, ListPatientForEnterHDActivity.class);
                    intent1.setAction(action);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data successfully entered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    startActivity(intent1);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No blank values allowed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });

        reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                etSystolic.setText("");
                etDiastolic.setText("");
                etDate.setText("");
                etTime.setText("");
            }
        });

        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(EnterBloodPressureActivity.this, ListPatientForEnterHDActivity.class);
                intent.setAction(action);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }

    protected void closePatientBPDatabase() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.close();
    }

    protected void openPatientBPDatabase() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("HCDatabase", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PatntBP (GroupName VARCHAR, PatientName VARCHAR, systolic VARCHAR, diastolic VARCHAR, date VARCHAR, time VARCHAR);");
    }

}
```

Comment: I do not see any code that tries to show the date on the x axis.

Comment: oh okay. Can you please help me in this? I am trying a lot lot, but i am not getting this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Write my code for me" questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow. You should at least look up the documentation of the graph component (whatever it is) before posting here.

Comment: okay. Sorry if i have done anything wrong.